GFCI for Refrigerator in Garage?
I'm putting a refrigerator in my garage and installing a separate 20-amp circuit for it.  I'd prefer to avoid issues that might arise if there are nuisance trips.  Does code require that a refrigerator in a garage be on a GFCI circuit?

Should check with your local building department.  Newer code wants every receptacle in a garage on GFCI protection, why a lot of EV chargers are recommended to be hardwired instead of plug in.  Newer fridges should play nicer with GFCI.

You might want to attach another cable to the load side of the garage GFCI and run it to a junction box up high on the wall in your living space. Put an indicator light and power-out alarm in the junction box. Then you'll know when the GFCI trips.

I am curious about the premise of this question: you expect that GFCI will induce more unexpected disconnections? I am French and I think your GFCI is equivalent to our differential protection circuit and all of the circuits must be on it (so also refrigerators).Why would a refrigerator trip the circuit more? (I am genuinely curious)

@WoJ  I don't think the concern is that a refrig will trip the circuit more. It's that if it should trip, being on a dedicated circuit, you might not know about it for a few days if you don't go into the refrig. Are your refrigerators on dedicated, separate circuits or do the share the circuit with other loads?

@JACK ah ok, I did not think about that. I am not sure what GFCI has to do with this (real) problem then. I have one refrigerator and teenagers to complain when it is empty or disconnected :)

My two refrigerators and a freezer are each on dedicated circuits.  I think I'll add a temperature sensing unit with an alarm to the refrigerator.  I found an "ambient weather" sensor on Amazon that will allow me to monitor both refrigerators and the freezer. It has an alarm to let me know if the temperature drops due to a mechanical breakdown of the refrigerator, or if a breaker trips.

@WoJ our GFCIs do the same thing as your RCD differential devices, however, our single purpose was human safety so ours are set quite sensitive at 5 mA.   This is why we can't use one for the whole house.  A house full of wiring will have more than 5mA natural leakage. EU RCDs are a compromise setting of 30mA for excellent live-earth arc fault protection, significant but not ideal human safety protection, and sensible cost with only 1-3 needed per home.

@Harper-ReinstateMonica ahh, thanks a lot for the very detailed answer. I now understand many other questions here related to that topic when I was always wondering "it looks like that are saying there is one differential per circuit and it it always tripping - how come our work?". Now I know that they work but 5 mA is >> for safety than 30 mA :) Thanks again

The latest national version of code requires it, yes.  But that's probably not your question?
The question is more about local exceptions, local enforcement, and your desire to be more or less compliant.  You say you'd rather not but I'd guess that if it is required and enforced and if your fridge is happy with a GFCI you'd be happy to benefit from the safety it provides.  Right?  Or even if it's not enforced you might want that.  Or you might want to avoid doing so.  Your inspector might insist regardless of the nuances, or the opposite: might give you a pass for a fridge even if local code requires it.
There's no internet answer.
You COULD install a 2-gang box for the fridge, install a GFCI, and a blank cover on the other side.  Use the GFCI for your fridge. You'll benefit from its protection and you'll never know if not using GFCI would have failed inspection.  If it ever trips, long after your inspection, you can install an unprotected single outlet in the second gang.
You can also install a cheap wifi energy monitor or other smart device that will notify you if the fridge shuts down.

I agree with this answer, however the issue arises when the alarm goes off and you are away on vacation.  For that reason I would instal a single standard outlet high up on the wall where the fridge cord reaches and it is not likely that anyone else would be able to plug anything else in without unplugging the fridge. This would make it a difficult outlet to use for anything but the fridge.  Maybe not compliant, but practical until an inspector tells me it's not...if ever.

@RMDman  On vacation and the power goes out for the house leaves you in the same boat.

I think RMDMan is contemplating the first-ever GFCI nuisance fault long after installation and coincidentally during an absence.  I find installing a ceiling-height outlet for this far-fetched scenario to be a little overkill.  That's what insurance is for.  But the general idea of thinking in detail about the risks you are trying to avoid is 100%.  For power loss on vacation you need a whole-house backup system.  You'll spend $20K to save a few steaks?  Nah.

I probably should have mentioned that I already have installed a single (not duplex) outlet for the refrigerator near the floor where the cord for the refrigerator is.  If I make the circuit GFCI, I'll do it at the breaker so that I can reset it without getting behind the refrigerator.  Please also note that I already have a 17kw whole house generator with an automatic transfer switch.  I don't have to worry about power outages when I'm gone.  OP

@Mark, With that info, I'd leave out the GFCI breaker until and I was told I had to replace it.

I'm going ahead with putting a GFCI breaker on the circuit.  Thanks to everyone who weighed in.  Your advice also helped me recognize I needed to have a common for the EV charging outlet I roughed in.   I easily replaced the cable while the wall was open.

@Mark you probably want to hardwire that EV charger...
